# "configure: error: could not find Python headers" and syntax error when running "make" to install deskbar-applet-2.32.0

Tags: command-line, software-installation, python, make

I am new to Ubuntu. I was trying to install deskbar-applet-2.32.0, but the make command doesn't work.

```
(base) jo18@jo18:~/Downloads/deskbar-applet-2.32.0$ ./configure
```

returns this error:

```
checking for headers required to compile python extensions...   File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; print sys.prefix
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; print sys.exec_prefix
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
not found
configure: error: could not find Python headers
```

My /usr/local/lib has got 4 folders:

```
python2.7
python3.6
python3.7
R
```

On running

```
(base) jo18@jo18:~/Downloads/deskbar-applet-2.32.0$ ./configure PYTHON=/usr/local/lib/python3.7
```

I get:

```
Using config source xml:merged:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults for schema installation
Using $(sysconfdir)/gconf/schemas as install directory for schema files
checking whether /usr/local/lib/python3.7 version >= 2.4... configure: error: too old
```

Python versions present in my computer:

```
(base) jo18@jo18:~/Downloads/deskbar-applet-2.32.0$ ls /usr/bin | grep python
dh_python2
python
python2
python2.7
python2.7-config
python2-config
python2-futurize
python2-pasteurize
python3
python3.6
python3.6m
python3.7
python3.7-config
python3.7m
python3.7m-config
python3m
python-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7m-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python-config
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot with Windows 10. The `(base)` appears in terminal since I installed anaconda-navigator.

Comment: What Ubuntu version do you use, and why do you have a Python **2.0** version installed/how and from where did you install that? Also looks like you're in a virtual environment for that specific Python version (looking at the `(base)` in your prompt).

Answer (score 2):

The last line of the `configure` script is giving you an error:

```
checking whether usr/local/lib/python2.0 version >= 2.4... configure: error: too old
```

First, you seem to be giving `usr/local/lib/python2.0`, which means "use the python found in the directory `usr` which **is inside the current directory**". I think you probably meant `/usr`, not `usr`.

In any case, if you have both python2 and 2.4 installed, you will need to point the configure script to the 2.4 version since that's what it needs. So try running this (assuming you have python 2.4 in `/usr/local/lib/python2.4`):

```
./configure PYTHON=/usr/local/lib/python2.4
```

If that works, try `make` again.

Comment: it didnt work and i edited the question with more details. any further help is appreciated.

Comment: !!! checking whether /usr/local/lib/python2.7/ version >= 2.5... configure: error: too old

Comment: @Estatistics if you have a new question please ask it separately. Explain what you are doing, the exact command you ran and the error you got. That said, the error seems quite obvious, you have an old python version.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/configure-configure-error-python-headers-not-found.html)!

> Usually /usr/bin/python should be just a symbolic link to Python3 or
> Python2,
>
> if it is to point to Python3, the we need to remove the link, and then
> create a symbolic link to Python2
>
> `rm /usr/bin/python`
>
> `ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`
>
> This creates a symbolic link for Python2.7, that doesn't need to
> restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while building the miro library. The `python version` seems to be wrong, instead the flag `--version` needs to be passed,

```
./configure PYTHON="/absolue_path_to_your_enviroment/bin/python2"
```

and in the configure script change the version to `--version`.

Also change in configure script from

```
#include <Python.h>
```

to,

```
#include <python2.7/Python.h>
```